# How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: css, visual-studio, google-chrome, caching

I'm currently editing a .css file inside of Visual Studio 2012 (in debug mode). I'm using Chrome as my browser. When I make changes to my application's .css file inside of Visual Studio and save, refreshing the page will not load with the updated change in my .css file. I think the .css file is still cached.

I have tried:

1. CTRL / F5
2. In Visual Studio 2012,
   Go to project properties, Web tab
   Choose Start External Program in the Start Action section
   Paste or browse to the path for Google Chrome (Mine is C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
   In the Command line arguments box put -incognito
3. Used the Chrome developer tools, click on the "gear" icon, checked "Disable Cache."

Nothing seems to work unless I manually stop debugging, (close out of Chrome), restart the application (in debug).

Is there any way to force Chrome to always reload all css changes and reload the .css file?

Update:
1. In-line style changes in my .aspx file are picked up when I refresh. But changes in a .css file does not. 
2. It is an ASP.NET MVC4 app so I click on a hyperlink, which does a GET. Doing that, I don't see a new request for the stylesheet. But clicking F5, the .css file is reloaded and the Status code (on the network tab) is 200.

Comment: f12 -> network -> right-click -> clear browser cache(I don't like it, so I use firefox with firebug)

Comment: I just tried that too. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you try refreshing it after all the menial right-clicks and clicks?

Comment: Yes. I also made a change in my .aspx file. It picked up the change and in-line css changes, just not changes in the .css file.

Comment: at the same network tab, you may see the entry of your `.css` file - I don't know asp so I can't be sure, but on my python flask dev server cached entries' status code is 304 while re-downloaded files have 200. check your status code and request time to see if it's server-side problem.

Comment: strange, i dont have a similar problem with netbeans/linux and chrome.  it always reloads css for me after i change it.

Comment: I created an addon that handles exactly your use case (force refresh CSS when it's changed): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-reload/jcejoncdonagmfohjcdgohnmecaipidc

Answer (score 165, accepted):

There are much more complicated solutions, but a very easy, simple one is just to add a random query string to your CSS include.

Such as `src="/css/styles.css?v={random number/string}"`

If you're using php or another server-side language, you can do this automatically with `time()`. So it would be `styles.css?v=<?=time();?>`

This way, the query string will be new every single time. Like I said, there are much more complicated solutions that are more dynamic, but in testing purposes this method is top (IMO).

Comment: just don't use this on production or you will lose the caching capabilities of your css. which is a good thing.

Comment: What if you're using a single page application and you need to tell the application to reload the CSS because the version has changed?

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch you change the version when the version changes instead of doing random/time string which changes everytime. Best approach will be to use checksum of the css file itself.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer for beginners? How exactly would you "just add a random query string"? Beginners want to be able to see changes in their work, too, and most of us have no idea what any of this means or how to search for an answer.

Comment: @randy I gave an example using *php* in which you render the current timestamp as a query parameter. You can research how to do something similar using whatever language you have on the backend. You can also do this through a grunt/gulp build step, if you have that at your disposal.

Comment: We used the current build number eg. src="/css/styles.css?v=@buildNumber to automaticly update the string with new releases

Comment: Worked only one time.... I'm confused. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: EDIT: I ended up using the solution of @marmick

Comment: I use this on PHP `src="/css/styles.css?v=<?=filemtime('css/styles.css');?>"` which sets the datetime last modification of the file

Answer (score 249):

To force chrome to reaload css and js:

Windows option 1: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
Windows option 2: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

OS X: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

> Updated as stated by @PaulSlocum in the comments (and many confirmed)

---

*Original answer:*

Chrome changed behavior. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will do it.

On OS X: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

> If you have problems reloading css/js files, open the inspector 
>   (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) before
>   doing the reload.

Comment: And here I was pressing CTRL+F5 like crazy... Thanks.

Comment: Another tip to try: 
http://www.code-pal.com/quick-tip-clear-cache-hard-refresh-on-chrome/

Comment: @duyn9uyen Good point! Looks like they are changing behavior again. This is added to chrome windows version, not yet available on mac.

Comment: Ctrl + R also working in Firefox. Thanks for Relieving me from Random Url and other things.

Comment: Life changing tip: I can now keep my right hand on the mouse!

Comment: @AdvaitS not at all. updated the answer to reflect OS X

Comment: Ctrl + R does not work on newest version, is identical to standard refresh.

Comment: CTRL+R does not work for me, but CTRL+SHIFT+R does it

Comment: I had to do CTRL+SHIFT+R twice.

Comment: ctrl+shift+r works like a charm in chromium under linux.

Comment: I'm sorry but those shortcuts do not refresh only the css and js files. They do a full refresh avoiding the cache. Open the inspector on the network tab and you will see this easily on the size column. On a simple F5 press the webpage it's refreshed using the cache. If you do shift+F5 or shift+R you will force a full refresh avoiding the cache.

Answer (score 154):

[READ THE UPDATE BELOW]

Easiest way I've found is in Chrome DevTools settings.
Click on the gear icon (or 3 vertical dots, in more recent versions) in the top-right of DevTools to open the "Settings" dialog. 
In there, tick the box: "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"

---

UPDATE: Now this setting has been moved. It can be found in the "Network" tab, it's a checkbox labeled "Disable Cache".
[image]

Comment: This is the best solution IMHO: you don't have to mess around with your own code to provide random value to your css url.

Comment: Excellent answer !... Worked like a charm !

Comment: I also found this one is the best solution.

Comment: This has been moved in more recent versions of Chrome: go to Network tab and check "Disable cache" in header.

Comment: The Ctrl+Shift+R and Shift+F5 methods don't work for me - guessing something changed in Chrome recently. This method still works great. @JasonClemens: the "Disable cache" option is in both the Network tab and in the Settings.

Comment: @Amos CTRL+SHIFT+R (CMD+SHIFT+R on Mac) still works for me on Chrome 63 (latest version as of today.)

Comment: Thanks, @AmosM.Carpenter. It had moved around and I didn't see it in settings, but I do confirm that it's there as well as the Network tab, which was how I usually access it.

Answer (score 11):

You are dealing with the problem of browser cache.

Disable the cache in the page itself. That will not save supporting file of page in browser/cache.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
```

This code you require/need to insert in `head` tag of the page you are debugging, or in `head` tag of  `master page` of your site

This will not allow browser to cache file, eventually files will not be stored in browser temporary files, so no cache, so no reloading will be required :)

I am sure this will do :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @anson 's solution didn't work, for me.

Answer (score 8):

In my case,in Chrome DevTools settings, just set "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"  doesn't work, it needs to check "Enable CSS source maps" and "Auto-reload generated CSS",which are listed in source group, to make this cache issue go away.

Answer (score 7):

i had faced same problem here! but I sure,my resolution is better than all above examples,just do this,

1. Pull up the Chrome developer console by pressing F12
2. Right click on the reload button at the top of the browser and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload."

That`s it!

Comment: life changing !

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

It is working for me with Chrome version 54.

Comment: Thank you.  Despite ctrl-r being the popular answer on this thread, only shift-f5 worked for me (Chromium 55).

Answer (score 6):

I'm using **Edge** Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit) and its based on the Chromium open source project.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to get into Dev Tools.
Click Network Tab
Check Disable cache
[image]

Answer (score 5):

With macOS I can force Chrome to reload the CSS file in by doing

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Found this answer buried in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403336/3511819) but it deserved more exposure.

Answer (score 3):

Current version of Chrome (55.x) does not reload all resources when you reload the page (Command + R) - and that is not useful for debugging the .css file.

Command + R works fine if you want to debug only the .html, .php, .etc files, and is faster because works with local/cached resources (.css, .js).
To manually delete browser's cache for each debug iteration is not convenient.

Procedure to force reload .css file on Mac (Keyboard Shortcut / Chrome): 
Command + Shift + R

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but if anyone is still looking how to reload just a single external css/js file, the easiest way now in Chrome is:

1. Go to *Network tab* in DevTools
2. Right click on the resource and select *Replay XHR* to repeat the request

Make sure that the *Disable cache* option is selected to force the reload.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS Chrome:

1. Open developers tools <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
2. Click three dots on the top right corner in developers tools
3. Click settings
4. Scroll down to `Network`
5. Enable `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)` see screenshot:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Why is it needed to refresh the whole page? Just refresh only css files without reloading the page. It is very helpful when, for example, you have to wait a long response from DB. Once you  get data from DB and populate the page, then edit your css files and reload them in Chrome (or in Firefox). To do that you need to install [CSS Reloader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-reloader/dnfpcpfijpdhabaoieccoclghgplmpbd?hl=en). Firefox version is also available.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste this script into Chrome console and it forces your CSS scripts to reload every 3 seconds. Sometimes I find it useful when I'm improving CSS styles.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('link');
[].forEach.call(nodes, function (node) {
    node.href += '?___ref=0';
});
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    i++;

    [].forEach.call(nodes, function (node) {
        node.href = node.href.replace(/\?\_\_\_ref=[0-9]+/, '?___ref=' + i);
    });
    console.log('refreshed: ' + i);
},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by this simple trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var style = 'assets/css/style.css?'+Math.random();;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<link href="'+style+'" rel="stylesheet">');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue.

Using parameters like "..css?something=random-value" changes nothing in my customer-support experience. Only name changes works.

Another take on the file renaming. I use URL Rewrite in IIS. Sometimes Helicon's Isapi Rewrite.

Add new rule.

```
+ Name: lame-chrome-fix.
+ Pattern: styles/(\w+)_(\d+)
+ Rewrite URL: /{R:1}.css
```

Note: I reserve the use of undercase to separate the name from the random number. Could be anything else.

Example:

```
<link href="/styles/template_<% 
Response.Write( System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddmmyyhhmmss")); %>" 
type="text/css" />
```

(No styles folder it's just a name part of the pattern)

Output code as:

```
<link href="/styles/template_285316115328" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Redirect as:

(R:1 = template)

/template.css

Only the explanation is long.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add your working directory to your Chrome "workspace" which allows Chrome to map local files to those on the page. It will then detect changes in the local files, and update the page in real-time.

This can be done from the "Sources" tab of Devtools:

[image]

Click on the "Filesystem" tab in the file browser sidebar, then click the +Plus sign button to "Add folder to workspace" - you will be prompted with a banner at the top of the screen to allow or deny local file access:

[image]

Once allowed, the folder will appear in the "Filesystem" tab on the left. Chrome will now attempt to associate each file in the filesystem tab with a file in the page. Sometimes you will need to reload the page once for this to function correctly.

Once this is done, Chrome should have no trouble picking up local changes, in fact you won't even need to reload to get the changes in many cases, and you can make edits to the local files directly from Devtools (which is extremely useful for CSS, it even comments out CSS lines when you toggle the checkboxes in the Styles tab).

[More information on Workspaces in Chrome.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces)

Comment: Suggestions to set the "disable cache" flag or "Command + Shift + R" - don't work in my case, but the answer of @zeel - did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem where one person running Chrome (on a Mac) suddenly stopped loading the CSS file. CMD + R did NOT work at all. I don't like the suggestions above that force a permanent reload on the production system.

What worked was changing the name of the CSS file in the HTML file (and renaming the CSS file of course). This forced Chrome to go get the latest CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sublime Text 3, using a build system to open the file opens the most current version and provides a convenient way to load it via [CTRL + B]
To set up a build system that opens the file in chrome:

1. Go to 'Tools'
2. Hover your mouse over 'build system'. At the bottom of the list brought up, click 'New Build System...'
3. In the new build system file type this:

   ```
   {"cmd": [ "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"]}
   ```

**provided the path stated above in the first set of quotes is the path to where chrome is located on your computer, if it isn't simply find the location of chrome and replace the path in the first set of quotes with the path to chrome on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to achieve your goal is to **open a new incognito window** in your chrome or **private window in firefox** which will by default, not cache.

You can use this for development purposes so that you don't have to inject some random cache preventing code in your project.

If you are using IE then may god help you!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Both work

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way on Safari 11.0 macOS SIERRA 10.12.6:
Reload Page From Origin, you can use help to find out where in the menu it is located, or you can use the shortcut option(alt) + command + R.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down Ctrl and click the Reload button. Or, Hold down Ctrl and press F5. just open the Chrome Dev Tools by pressing F12. Once the chrome dev tools are open, just right click on the refresh button and a menu will drop down.

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS files you can use the *Reload CSS* extension for Google Chrome.

It will only reload the CSS without the need to refresh all the web or resend the last form.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reload-css/ckaofffdgmblmfkglibpaleigpldjjem

Answer (score -1):

`Chrome/firefox/safari/IE` will reload the entire  page by these shortcuts

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd>  (OR) <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**F5**</kbd>

Hope it may helps you!.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SiteGround as your hosting company and none of the other solutions have worked, try this:

From the cPanel, go to "SITE IMPROVEMENT TOOLS" and click "SuperCacher." On the following page, click the "Flush Cache" button.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with Visual Studio nor the Chrome browser. Also, this question was asked 4 **years** ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a new and improved solution to the problem. Check out the documentation on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Comment: Hi Obsidian. My apologies. It's the first time I've posted here. I searched long and hard for a solution to this problem. The accepted answer didn't work for me. When I did find a solution (through my own research), I wanted to "pay it forward" by helping anyone else who encounters this problem -even if it is four years old. I'm not sure why my action here would warrant a slap on the wrist, as it seems legit to me. Nevertheless, I'll be sure to be careful in the future (truly -I don't mean that in a snarky way). Thanks -Don.