# Django Static Files Won't Reload On Firefox

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

For some reason the CSS files for my Django webpages won't load in. It originally was loading fine, and changes to the CSS would update accordingly, however often it stops updating the CSS as it is changed, and instead continues loading the previous version of the CSS file. Quitting and reopening the server does not work.

The CSS loads in fine on Chrome and Safari, so it can't be a problem with the static path I don't think. Does anyone have any clue as to why this occurs and any way to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: if you open developer tools in Chrome, disable cache and load your page does it work? It sounds like a caching issue at the browser level.

Comment: Try pressing `ctrl + F5` to do a hard refresh, or try to use incognito mode. As stated above looks like a caching issue.

Comment: Hi thank you very much that has worked. Why does this occur?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio