# Django not updating static css file design in browser when I run collect static command

Tags: django

I wrote css file and then save it all changes happen and when I run collect static command and then I again change css files no changes displayed on browser nothing happen at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to cache problem. So, you can try this on your browser which will reload from start:

```
Ctrl + R
```

Comment: delete the static files django collected inside of yourProjectName/static then run collect static command again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to double check the `settings.py` if the `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_URL` is declared there. An example below-

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    'static',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
```

Then create a `static` folder and `media` folder where `manage.py` file is located. Then run the `python3 manage.py collectstatic`. Hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

It is due to catch problem.

```
ctrl +f5
```

Is the solution