# Django web app css not being refreshed in browser

Tags: css, django

I'm having some issue with a django app and it's CSS file refreshing. Basically I can see that the changes I make in my file are identified and copied in the root folder of my website, however when I open up the web browser that change is not being displayed at all:

[image: The style.css copied in the root folder]

[image: My style.css]

[image: My browser not picking up on the changes]

I am using Firefox as a browser however this issue happens also on Chromium browser

Comment: What if you use Ctrl+F5? Likely the style sheet is being cached by the browser.

Comment: Tried that too a bunch, didn't help with this issue

Comment: Also closing and restarting the server a few times

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: @dustin-we Yes ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup everything well in your settings.py file then your best option is to disable caching form your developer panel.
I had similar issues when I make changes in css and they are not updated when i refresh my browser. This is because the browser is keeping a cache of the css file and its not being updated for some reason.

So according to [this](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/changes-in-css-style-sheet-not-reflecting-in-the-page/2742) post,you can disable caching

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).