# Browser loads an empy css

Tags: python, css, django, pycharm

css located in my_blog/my_blog/blog/static/blog/style.css
manage.py in my_blog/my_blog
head of html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title%} My blog {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

I'm using pycharm pro. Browser successfully load css file, but it's empty. Why this is happenning?

I don't see css loading in django console log, when pages load. I changed name of css file. And it's loaded, but once.

When I add new rule to it and reload server, browser still get old version of css.

Now it's works fine. Css loaded properly. I didn't change anything, so I don't know what did happen.

Comment: Can you share your `settings.STATIC_ROOT` variable?

Comment: @NixonSparrow, don't have one. Only STATIC_URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Chrome browser to reload .css file while debugging in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562384/how-to-force-chrome-browser-to-reload-css-file-while-debugging-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings.py:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Then move your `static` folder to project's folder - `/my_blog/static/blog/style.css` instead of the current one.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe your href is formatted properly

Comment: I did it like in this tut: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial06/
What's wrong with that?

Comment: @CheshireCat It looks ok, I do it like you. Is it possible, that you have few files `blog/style.css` in different apps?

Comment: @NixonSparrow, nope. No different apps. Only blog and my_blog.